# How I can reset the People Picker height on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, master-page, css, layouts

I am facing a problem on IE 10 32-bit, where the People Picker will not show the people correctly,  as the area seems to be minimized. Here is what I get from IE developer tools:-

[image]

Now if I manually change the inner style height from 45px to 400 px the dialog will be shown correctly, as follow:-

[image]

now using JavaScript I wrote the following script and I added it to the master page, but this will not have any effect. Could this be that the script will not work on newly rendered content such as the dialog and I need to specify a .live() for it ?
here is the script to set the height :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#resultcontent").css("height","400px");
    $(".ms-pickerresultdiv").css("height","400px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its seems Microsoft is evaluating height value dynamically. Hence your code has no effect.

You can try adding below CSS into your Master Page

```
#resultcontent {
    height: 400px !important
}
.ms-pickerresultdiv {
    height: 400px !important
}
```

Comment: ok i added your code inside my custom CSS which is loaded after the defualt css, but this will not solve the problem and i can not see any differences in the People Picker ...seems all these techniques do not affect the dialog for some reason,,, not sure why

Comment: Another option you can try is to force compatibility mode using `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >`

Comment: can you advice on what will this meta do ? i am using IE10 not IE8

Comment: can you adivce on this ? as i am using IE10 so why i need to add compatibility for IE8 ?

Comment: For example we tested one of our customer SP implementation on IE9, and ensured no issues are there. Then we added meta tag for IE9. So even if someone uses IE 10, it rendered in IE9 mode and everything will works as expected. My comment was just a suggestion you can try it out.

Comment: so you mean if i add <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" > to the master page then SP will always be rendered as if it is working on IE8 ?  i do not think this is recommended approach... what do u think ?